# Difference between ImmutableArray<T> and ImmutableList<T>

Tags: c#, .net, immutable-collections

What is difference between `ImmutableArray<T>` and `ImmutableList<T>`, and where would it be best to use each?

Comment: One's an array, and the other is a list?

Comment: I am asking about immutability

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you are asking where to use each of them. [Please welcome ImmutableArray](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/please-welcome-immutablearrayt/) will help.  To summarize, use immutable array when:

> - Updating the data is rare or the number of elements is quite small (<16)
> - You need to be able to iterate over the data in performance critical sections
> - You have many instances of immutable collections and you can’t afford keeping the data in trees

Use immutable list when:

> - Updating the data is common or the number of elements isn't expected to be small
> - Updating the collection is more performance critical than iterating the contents

Comment: This answer appears to be copied from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/24/please-welcome-immutablearray.aspx without proper attribution. -1

Comment: What does it even mean to "update the data" in an immutable structure?

Comment: Usually I use `List` instead.

Comment: @M-Pixel It means "create a new version with an element altered, added, or removed". The list does this efficiently, the array does not.

Answer (score 34):

Here is some reading that might help explain: [Please welcome ImmutableArray](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/please-welcome-immutablearrayt/)

Here's an excerpt:

> Reasons to use immutable array:
>
> - Updating the data is rare or the number of elements is quite small (<16)
> - you need to be able to iterate over the data in performance critical sections
> - you have many instances of immutable collections and you can’t afford keeping the data in trees
>
> Reasons to stick with immutable list:
>
> - Updating the data is common or the number of elements isn’t expected to be small
> - Updating the collection is more performance critical than iterating the contents

Answer (score 7):

The main difference is that an `ImmutableArray` is just a wrapper around a normal array, which means that retrieving elements within the array is extremely quick.

An `ImmutableArray` is also a struct, meaning that it's a value type, so it takes up less space than an Immutable List which is a reference type.

For these reasons, an `ImmutableArray` is suitable to use if you rarely need to update its data, or the number of elements is small (less than 16), or if the performance of iterating over the collection is important.

If your needs do not match the reasons above, you should use an `ImmutableList`.

Look here for the [documentation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/please-welcome-immutablearrayt/).

Comment: The link completely answers this question. But your remark on value-type and size is dodgy.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray%28v=vs.111%29.aspx), it’s a class, not a struct. Even primitive arrays are reference types—if they were structs the compiler would have to know the number of elements in the array ahead of time like how C supports inline packed arrays (not sure that’s the right terminology).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn638264(v=vs.111).aspx suggests it is a struct?

Comment: @binki: you are looking at the wrong doc page. The class `ImmutableArray` is simply a _static_ class with helper methods. The actual object itself is a `struct`. That said, I do agree that this post is making unwarranted statements about value types, the accuracy of the statement of what kind of type `ImmutableArray<T>` is notwithstanding.

Answer (score 5):

Going by the blog post "[Please welcome ImmutableArray<T>](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/06/24/please-welcome-immutablearrayt/)" (the same blog post everyone else is referencing), the differences are...

`ImmutableArray`:

- Simple implementation (just an array).
- Not optimized for quickly updating large collections (the entire array needs to be copied).
- More efficient for most use cases (anything that does *not* involve updating large collections).

`ImmutableList`:

- More complicated implementation (something involving trees).
- **Is** optimized for quickly updating large collections (it can be done in logarithmic time).
- Less efficient for most use cases.

So if you're not updating much, or your collections are small, use `ImmutableArray`. If you're going to be frequently updating large collections, you'll need to use `ImmutableList`.